# iOS - App Runs On iPhone 5s But Not iPhone SE

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time I run my app on my iPhone 5s, it works. However, every time I try to run the app on my co-worker's iPhone SE, I get the following error message:

```
App Installation Failed: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so, actually. If that were the case, it wouldn't be running on my iPhone 5s

Comment: @Rafi the provisioning profile has a list of devices associated with it. Just because it runs on one devices doesn't mean it will run on others.

Comment: Look at the most up voted answer to that question. Not the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added the device to the provisioning profile but forgot to re-download the newly generated one! *face palm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the iPhone SE as a test device: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/